# trouble with this parameter c#

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x,y;
            int opt;   
               Console.Write Line(" input ");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(y);
                y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
                {
                    switch (x)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                            Console.Write("Press any key to continue");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                            Console.Write("Press any key to continue");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                            Console.Write("Press any key to continue");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                            Console.Write("Press any key to continue");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                            Console.Write("Press any key to continue");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            break;`enter code here`
                        default:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid color");
                            break;
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                } while (color != 0) ;
            }
        }
    }
```

having a problem with this code why? there any thing wrong about it? please help.
    i think some  of code   in-valid but i dont know what is that i try to run this and 
    its running

Comment: What line of the code is the compiler complaining about? What error do you get?

Answer (score 3):

1: You are trying to use the variable `y` before it has been assigned a value:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(y);
```

2: You have code after the `break;` in the default case in the switch:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

3: The variable `color` is never defined:

```
} while (color != 0) ;
```

4: You are using `while` at the end bracket of a `for` loop. That will instead become its own loop and get stuck if the condition was true, as the content of the loop is an empty statement where the condition can't change:

```
} while (color != 0) ;
```

Also, the variable `opt` is never used, and the value in the variable `y` is never used once you have set it. It looks like you are getting input and try to act on it, but is looping and acting on the loop variable instead.